# innerHTML = var writes to console instead of to page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

When I try to use the following code, innerHTML writes to the dev console instead of replacing the page body with myTable.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('body').innerHTML = myTable;
```

myTable is simply a series of text items formatting into a table. I have tried using jQuery

```
$("body").html(myTable);
```

However, I am trying to do this exclusively in javascript due to complications.

Full code below:

```
var titleArray = [];
var descArray = [];
var myTable = "<table><thead><tr><th>Index</th><th>Item Name</th>
<th>Description</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

var doc = top.frames['bsscright'].document;
titleArray = doc.getElementsByTagName('dt');
descArray = doc.getElementsByTagName('dd');

for (var i = 0; i < titleArray.length; i++) {
  myTable+="<tr><td>" + i + "</td>";
  myTable+="<td>" + titleArray[i].innerText + "</td>";
  myTable+="<td>" + descArray[i].innerText + "</td></tr>";
}

myTable+="</thead></table>";

document.getElementsByClassName('body').innerHTML = myTable;
```

Can anyone tell me why .innerHTML = simply outputs my table in text form to console, instead of writing my table to the page?

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to set an html of an element with class body, not <body> element of the document? Most likely you are seeing an exception in console. try document.body.innerHTML = myTable

Comment: You really mean getElementsByClassName or getElementsByTagName? Or check Dimitri comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelector` instead to get the first `body` class, which seems to be what you want.

```
document.querySelector('.body').innerHTML = myTable;
```

Otherwise you're setting the `.innerHTML` property of the collection returned instead of on a specific element.

---

Also, you could use template strings to make this nicer.

```
var doc = top.frames['bsscright'].document;
var titleArray = doc.getElementsByTagName('dt');
var descArray = doc.getElementsByTagName('dd');

var myTable = "<table><thead><tr><th>Index</th><th>Item Name</th>
<th>Description</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

for (var i = 0; i < titleArray.length; i++) {
  myTable += `<tr><td>${i}</td>
                  <td>${titleArray[i].textContent}</td>
                  <td>${descArray[i].textContent}</td></tr>`;
}

document.querySelector('.body').innerHTML = myTable+"</thead></table>";
```

Comment: The OP might even just want `querySelector('body')` (without the class, because who adds a class called `body` to <body>?)

Comment: @Andy: True. Somethings odd there. If so, `document.body` would work too.